# ListView displaying nothing with custom adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

As the title states, I'm having some troubles getting my custom listview to work properly. The app displays nothing on the list, and gives just a blank white screen. I tested my data with a simple list I already have setup, and that worked just fine. I'm hoping someone can see something I haven't. Thanks.

History.java

```
public class History {
    public String score;
    public String gametype;
    public int icon;

    public History() {
        super();
    }

    public History(String score, String gametype, int icon) {
        super();
        this.score = score;
        this.gametype = gametype;
        this.icon = icon;
    }
}
```

HistoryAdapter.java

```
public class HistoryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<History> {

    Context context;
    int layoutResId;
    History data[] = null;

    public HistoryAdapter(Context context, int layoutResId, History[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResId, data);
        this.layoutResId = layoutResId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        HistoryHolder holder = null;

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResId, parent, false);

            holder = new HistoryHolder();
            holder.imageIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.textTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.gameType);
            holder.textScore = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.score);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (HistoryHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        History history = data[position];
        holder.textScore.setText(history.score);
        holder.textTitle.setText(history.gametype);
        holder.imageIcon.setImageResource(history.icon);


        return convertView;
    }

    static class HistoryHolder
    {
        ImageView imageIcon;
        TextView textTitle;
        TextView textScore;
    }
}
```

Implementation

```
History[] historyData = new History[games.length()];


for(int i = 0; i < games.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = games.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject gameStats = games.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject(TAG_STATS);
                    type[i] = c.getString(TAG_TYPE);
                    champId[i] = c.getString("championId");
                    cs[i] = gameStats.getString("minionsKilled");
                    kills[i] = gameStats.getString("championsKilled");
                    deaths[i] = gameStats.getString("numDeaths");
                    assists[i] = gameStats.getString("assists");
                    win[i] = gameStats.getString("win");

                    if(win[i].equals("true"))
                        win[i] = "Victory";
                    else
                        win[i] = "Defeat";

                    if(type[i].equals("RANKED_SOLO_5x5"))
                        type[i] = "Ranked (Solo)";

                    if(type[i].equals("CAP_5x5"))
                        type[i] = "TeamBuilder";

                    if(type[i].equals("NORMAL"))
                        type[i] = "Unranked";

                    score[i] = kills[i] +"/" + deaths[i] + "/" + assists[i];

                    historyData[i] = new History(score[i], champId[i], R.drawable.ic_launcher); // Placeholder image

                }

                if(historyData == null) {
                    historyData[0] = new History("No game found", "N/A", R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                    Log.i("Data", "" + historyData);
                }

                adapter = new HistoryAdapter(MatchHistoryActivity.this,
                        R.layout.list_adapter,
                        historyData);

                list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

listview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:background="#111111"> 
    </ListView>
```

list_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:background="#111111"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/score"
        android:textColor="#C49246"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="0/0/0 KDA"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gameType"
        android:textColor="#C49246"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/score"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The whole code seems ok to me, just one thing: Are you sure that `historyData` is not empty at the time you declare your `ArrayAdapter`?

Comment: @nKn I have added a code section to check if historyData is null, and I believe I implemented that correctly. If you could give it a look over, that'd be great.

Comment: You should also put some `Log.d()` sentences inside your loop to check if it's doing what it's supposed to, and also include the part where you initialize `historyData`.

Comment: @nKn I have added where I initialize it, but I ran into a bit of an issue. Using Log.d() statements in the loop, I found out that the loop is stopping. Reason being is that when, say, deaths for the game are 0, the JSON returned doesn't include that field at all. so there is no gameStats.getString("numDeaths") entry in the JSON. How would I handle it not being there in some cases?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getString%28java.lang.String%29 So basically surround the `.getString()` statement with try and if it raises a `JSONException`, you know it's not there. Probably your initial issue is coming from there.

Comment: @nKn Got it working is a try/catch block. Thanks for all the help. If you want to put your answer(s) into an answer and not a comment, I'll select it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've included seems fine, so the only point where it can fail is in the loop where you create the `historyData` array.

For some reason you might not be processing it correctly, for instance, some `JSON` attributes not being defined sometimes.

You can use a `try` block and catch a `JSONException` to see what's wrong, and also add several `Log.d()` sentences to know where's the culprit.

For instance:

```
try {
  cs[i] = gameStats.getString("minionsKilled");
}
catch (JSONException) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using wrong XML

Change

```
adapter = new HistoryAdapter(MatchHistoryActivity.this,
                        R.layout.list_adapter,historyData);
```

to

```
adapter = new HistoryAdapter(MatchHistoryActivity.this,
                        R.layout.list_item,historyData);
```

and make sure that your `historyData` is not null

Comment: I changed the file names in my headings for easier understanding. My list_adapter.xml file is really the typical list_item.xml file. Again, the contents of my list_adapter.xml is the above posted list_item.xml

Comment: Did you checked your `historyData` is null or not ?

Comment: I added in a section of code to check if it is null, and it is not printing a log indicating that it is. I have edited the added code into my main post above.